# Get Powerpoint data using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I got a couple of pictures on a scroll bar, that can be positioned independently. Now I want to run a script in Excel, that creates a Powerpoint instance and gets the Y-coordinate of a picture by its image ID.

```
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

PPApp.Visible = True
```

That's what I got so far, to create a Powerpoint instance. Now I don't really know how to tell Excel/VBA which ppt to read & how to give me the Y-coordinate on slide XY.

Comment: Google  terms like "control powerpoint from excel" or "automate powerpoint from excel" (without the quotes) to get lots of code examples.  That'll get you considerably closer. You'll need to open the presentation you want to work with.  From there, how will you know which slide the image is on?  You can find the image by looping through all the shapes on the slide checking each for an ID match.  The shape's .Top property will give you the Y coordinate (relative to the top of the slide, in Points)

Comment: Thanks! The image and slides are fairly static, so they'll always have the same image ID and it will always be the e.g. second slide. I'll give it a go